# Calling C# method from javascript in Sharepoint 2010 Webpart

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to call c# function from javascript the code i have tried is as below.

C# code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public void myFun()
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://google.com");
    }
```

In javascript i have tried following two codes

```
function CallMe(src, dest) {

    //First code i have tried

    //var ctrl = document.getElementById(src);
    // call server side method
    //PageMethods.myFun(CallSuccess, CallFailed, dest);

    //Second code i have tried
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: myFun, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //data: "{passedVal:" + JSON.stringify(clientRequest) + "}", dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("ERROR");
        }

    });
}

function CallSuccess(res, destCtrl) {
    alert("success");
}

function CallFailed(res, destCtrl) {
    alert("fail");
}
```

but both are not woking.
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"myFun" is a function of a WS?
If it is, in the url parameter you need to write the full function url on the WS, and not only it's name.

Hope that will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeh call it like so, page.aspx/MyFun